# Launch maximized or scrollable Global Quick Action for Screen Flow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, quickaction, screen-flow

I have seen the other answer linked for a potential solution for this issue, but I cannot get it to work.

I have a GQA which launches a screen flow - it does this fine. However, the modal not scrollable (and when made scrollable, extends the field with so that horizontal scrolling is now required).

I would like to either be able to add scroll behavior without altering the field widths in the modal so that horizontal scrolling is not required, or automatically pop out the screen flow.

The code below is what I attempted to implement scroll behavior (this also causes the same scroll behavior when maximized, making the UX clunky).

```
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
        <div class="slds-docked_container_align-right">
            <div class="slds-docked-modal_composer slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-right slds-grid_align-right slds-is-open slds-modal_large" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-heading-id-1" aria-describedby="dialog-content-id-1">
                <div class="slds-docked-composer__body slds-scrollable">
                    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aura:component>
```

It is also important to note that mobile functionality is not important at this time.